# Python if statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, printing, random, if-statement

I currently have the code:

```
fleechance = random.randrange(1,5)
print fleechance
if fleechance == 1 or 2:
    print "You failed to run away!"
elif fleechance == 4 or 3:
    print "You got away safely!"
```

fleechance is constantly printing as 3 or 4, but I continue to get the result "You failed to run away!" ,can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: This is not equivalent to `if fleechance == 1 or fleechance == 2`. It's equivalent to saying `if fleechance ==1: if 2`, which will always be true because `if 2` is true.

Comment: What Python tutorial are you using?  Where have you seen code like this?  Can you provide a like or a reference?  This code is quite bad, and it's important to know where you got the idea that it might be meaningful.

Comment: I have a book, but I didn't get the code directly from there, it just seemed that it would work, so I don't think that it's really the fault of the tutorial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `fleechance == 1 or 2` is equivalent to `(fleechance == 1) or (2)`. The number `2` is always considered “true”.

Try this:

```
if fleechance in (1, 2):
```

EDIT: In your situation (only 2 possibilities), the following will be even better:

```
if fleechance <= 2:
    print "You failed to run away!"
else:
    print "You got away safely!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if fleechance == 1 or fleechance == 2:
    print "You failed to run away!"
elif fleechance == 4 or fleechance == 3:
    print "You got away safely!"
```

Alternatively, if those are the only possibilites, you can do

```
if fleechance <= 2:
    print "You failed to run away!"
else:
    print "You got away safely!"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement is working as designed, the problem is that order of operations is causing this code to do something other than that you want.

The easiest fix would be to say:

```
if fleechance == 1 or fleechance == 2:
    print "You failed to run away!"
elif fleechance == 3 or fleechance == 4:
    print "You got away safely!"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, I didn't know about the order of operations.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not asking whether `fleechance` is 1 or `fleechance` is 2; you're asking whether

1. `fleechance` is 1, or
2. 2 is non-zero.

Of course, that second part of the condition is always true. Try

```
if fleechance == 1 or fleechance == 2:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it further, I'll try not to make the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote your if statements is wrong.
You tell python to check if fleechance equals 1 is true or if 2 is true.
A non-zero integer always means true in a condition.
You should wrote :

```
fleechance = random.randrange(1,5)
print fleechance
if fleechance == 1 or fleechance == 2:
    print "You failed to run away!"
elif fleechance == 4 or fleechance == 3:
    print "You got away safely!"
```